# Creating Python package fails because one file can't see the other

Tags: python, python-module

I have 3 files in a Python module called flags.

1. Empty `__init__.py` file
2. `data.py`
3. `lookup.py`

`lookup.py` contains the line `from data import list_of_data_items`

If I then try to run

```
from flags import lookup
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

Importing `data` works without issue

```
>>> from flags import data
>>>
```

Comment: can I put that in the init instead?

Comment: Tried both with no success. For the record I've tried importing with `import lookup` and `from lookup import *` no luck with either

Comment: found solution, in `lookup.py` change to the line `from .data import list_of_data_items` or `from flags.data import list_of_data_items`

Comment: That works very well. Thanks! If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Would also appreciate whatever reference you find most useful to learn more about creating Python modules.

Comment: I think answer is not required, you can read about relative imports here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time`

Comment: Great link thanks! An answer would provide a quick tldr for users who might not read the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lookup.py change to the line 
`from .data import list_of_data_items or from flags.data import list_of_data_items`

For further reading check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-import%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs-for-the-billionth-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btime) .